# Is there a way to set an angle between to edges?

Tags: edges

I've seen that it was part of the MeshTools-AddOn long time ago.

I know that I have several ways to measure angles (through the "Overlay", the "MeasureIt-AddOn" or the default Measuring in Blender) but measuring is not setting the angle...

Can you help me?

Comment: Any update on your question? Were you able to figure this out?